# How does one say "I need a place to stay"?

Tags: word-choice

I assume "todomerumono" or 留める物　is the "a place to stay".

Something like "留める物が要する"?

Since 要する is to need... It's a very direct translation.

I'm trying to write stories in Japanese to learn words, and this story involves the heroine asking for a place to stay.  The land is fantasy/magical and pre-industrial in case that affects word choice.

--- UPDATE ---

The heroine is saying it.

Comment: Is this sentence being used by the heroine to actually ask for a place to stay, or is it just a statement saying the heroine needs a place to stay?

Comment: @Blavius The heroine is asking it.

Comment: @user2738698 could you give a little more context of conversation? A few lines from it? This would help us point you to a more natural translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's more common in Japanese to use 'want' instead of 'need' (or just implications of necessity/desire) when you're talking about oneself--otherwise, it comes off as a bit strong or desperate. If the heroine is indeed asking in such a way, then sova's answer would work.

Otherwise, here are some roundabout (but more 'Japanese') ways to go about it:

> 泊まれるところを探していますが…
>   I'm looking for a place where I can stay [and would you happen to know of any?]...
>
> 泊まる場所、ありますか？
>   Is there a place to stay? [Hopefully in your house?]

Comment: +1 but using 「探しているのですが」 would be far  more natural than 「探していますが」.  At least that would be the native speaker's choice.

Answer (score 1):

You know, for a first guess, that's really good.  In modern Japanese I would probably say something like

泊まる場所がいる

泊まる場所 (tomaru basho = crashing/staying-place = a place to stay)

が (particle GA)

いる need

You can also riff on what you've got by saying

泊まる場所が必要です

必要です (hitsuyou desu) = is necessary

要する, although properly placed conceptually in translation, actually means something like "in summation" and in usually used in the form of 要するに.

(simple english / japanese example)
There were three thousand blue flowers, ten thousand green flowers, and five thousand white flowers, 要するに, there were a lot of flowers.